# SQL query works fine in TOAD , but not when placed in java code

Tags: java, sql

The following sql query executes fine when ran in TOAD editor and shows results,but does not fail or 
show results when placed in java code.

```
CREATE TABLE CDRRD.C31820_ADHOCM AS 
    SELECT A.REC_ID A_REC_ID, A.NORM_DUR A_DUR, A.NORM_STDT A_STDT, A.TOTAL_TYPE A_TT, B.REC_ID B_REC_ID, B.NORM_DUR B_DUR,  B.NORM_STDT B_STDT, 
           B.TOTAL_TYPE B_TT, 2180 SCENARIO_ID,3324 PAIR_ID,1 RECURSIVE_STAGE_ID FROM 
           (SELECT D.* FROM CDRRD.C31820_3445 D WHERE EXISTS (
                      SELECT E.* AS FROM CDRRD.C31820L E WHERE E.A_TT = 473 AND E.RECURSIVE_STAGE_ID = 1 AND E.A_REC_ID = D.REC_ID)) A , 
           (SELECT F.* FROM CDRRD.C31820_3440 F WHERE EXISTS (
                      SELECT G.* AS FROM CDRRD.C31820R G WHERE G.B_TT = 300 AND G.RECURSIVE_STAGE_ID = 1 AND G.B_REC_ID = F.REC_ID)) B 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CDRRD.C31820_ADHOC C WHERE  A.NORM_A = C.NORM_B AND C.NORM_A = B.NORM_A AND B.PAY_TYPE = C.PAY_TYPE AND A.PAY_TYPE = C.PAY_TYPE ) 
     AND TO_NUMBER ((a.norm_stdt - b.norm_stdt) * 86400) BETWEEN -90 AND 90 AND (b.norm_dur - a.norm_dur) BETWEEN -1 AND 2
```

Comment: Probably your java code would help instead of sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a create statement, what results do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you **commit** the transaction after the command is executed.

it would help to see the java code.

Comment: A commit would only be necessary if the DBMS supports transactional DDL. As *to_number()* is used, this could be Oracle or PostgreSQL. For the first no commit would be necessary, for the latter it would