# C#/.NET, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client - Exponentially slower execution time querying view vs. table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

This question is building off of a [previous question I've asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176789/sql-query-slow-execution-time-in-c-fast-execution-in-toad) -- and while I resolved that issue by increasing FetchSize, I need to now change the query from `SELECT * FROM TABLE1` to `SELECT * FROM VIEW1`, where `TABLE1`, and a couple of other tables in the database, are the base tables for `VIEW1`.

The code from the previous question is pretty much the same, but to account for the FetchSize change, breakpoints, and query:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create Connection
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

        // Create ConnectionString using Builder
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        ocsb.Password = "PASSWORD";
        ocsb.UserID = "USER1";
        ocsb.DataSource = "URL";

        // Connect 
        con.ConnectionString = ocsb.ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(">>> Connection Established");

        // Execute a SQL SELECT
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            // Breakpoint #1
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from VIEW1";
            // Breakpoint #2 
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.FetchSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Cache configuration
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            PeerAssemblyLoadingMode = Apache.Ignite.Core.Deployment.PeerAssemblyLoadingMode.CurrentAppDomain,
            CacheConfiguration = new[]
            {
                new CacheConfiguration
                {
                    Name = "cacheName",
                    Backups = 1,
                    QueryEntities = new[]
                    {
                        new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Table))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            // Breakpoint #3    
        IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
        ICache<int, Table> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Table>("cacheName");

            // Breakpoint #4    
        using (var stmr = ignite.GetDataStreamer<int, Table>("cacheName"))
        {
            // Add entries to cacheName
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                table.SetObject(reader);
                stmr.AddData(table.Id, table.Name);
            }
            // Clean up
            // Breakpoint #5
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**Table.cs**

```
class Table
    {
        [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void SetObject(OracleDataReader reader)
        {
            Id = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(0);
            Name = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1);
        }
    }
```

**View Definition**

```
DROP VIEW USER1.VIEW1;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW USER1.VIEW1
(
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    COL4,
    COL5,
    COL6,
    COL7
)
BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
    SELECT a.col1,
           a.col2,
           a.col3,
           a.col4,
           a.col5,
           a.col6,
           a.col7
      FROM table1           a,
           table2          ph,
           (  SELECT col1,
                     SUM (DECODE (user_type, 'Top User', 0, 1))
                         team_count,
                     SUM (DECODE (user_type, 'Top User', 1, 0))
                         top_user_count
                FROM view2
            GROUP BY col1) gat
     WHERE     A.col3 = UPPER (PH.col3(+))
           AND a.col1 = gat.col1(+);


CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM USER2.VIEW1 FOR USER1.VIEW1;

CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM USER3.VIEW1 FOR USER1.VIEW1;


GRANT SELECT ON USER1.VIEW1 TO ID1;

GRANT SELECT ON USER1.VIEW1 TO ID2;

GRANT SELECT ON USER1.VIEW1 TO ID3;

GRANT SELECT ON USER1.VIEW1 TO ID4;

GRANT SELECT ON USER1.VIEW1 TO ID5;
```

Getting from breakpoint #1 to #2 is done in under a second. However, the time in between breakpoint #2 and breakpoint #3 was exceeding 30 minutes before my computer disconnected from the internet (there were no errors/exceptions prior to the disconnect as the program and diagnostic session were both running).

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on why the program hangs on the line `OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, and why this is an issue I face once I switched from `TABLE` to `VIEW` in my query.

Comment: Please share the view definition.

Comment: And the query plan

Comment: @mjwills edited to add the view definition!

Comment: @JustinCave I'm new to oracle toad - where would I find the query plan?

Comment: The view is more complicated than the table - so it is not a surprise that querying the view is slower.

Comment: @mjwills How would you suggest I work around that?

Comment: Improve the performance of the view - e.g. add indexes. This is likely nothing to do with C#.

Comment: indeed your view is selecting into another view. Hope the second view does not select in another view and so on... Seems poor design to me.